# Show that if a and b have the same sign then |a| + |b| = |a + b|

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

We start with  a, b > 0.

We know that $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$, $|b| = \sqrt{b^2}$ and $|a+b| = \sqrt{(a+b)^2}$

We do the following :

$|a| + |b| = \sqrt{a^2} + \sqrt{b^2}$

$=a + b$

So : $|a| + |b| = a+b$

We take this result :

$|a| + |b| = a+b$

$(|a| + |b|)^2 = (a+b)^2$

$\sqrt{(|a| + |b|)^2} = \sqrt{(a+b)^2}$

$a+b =|a+b|$

Thus : |a+b|= |a| + |b|

For the case where a, b < 0, we use the same technique but with minuses before the constants Opinion ?

Comment: Your proof is correct for the case you cover. It's correct too in the other case if you put the minus signs in the right places - but "before the constants" doesn't really tell me where they will go. I think you know, but should say. In all cases there are better ways to describe $|x|$ than $\sqrt{x^2}$.

Comment: Yeah when I say before the constants I mean that you put "-" infront of a and b and just simplify it with power to two. You basically have this : $|-a| + |-b| = a+b$ . Using the same approach as a, b > or equal to 0. Right ? Edit : You're right. I didn't think about it to be honest I think I used the harder route...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $a\geq 0$ and $b\geq 0$ then
$$|a|+|b|=a+b=|a+b|.$$
If $a\leq 0$ and $b\leq 0$ then
$$|a|+|b|=-a-b=-(a+b)=|a+b|.$$

Comment: What ? Also, what about my approach ?

Comment: I am using the definition of absolute value, i.e. $|x|=x$ if $x\geq0$ and $|x|=-x$ if $x\leq 0$.

Comment: The details would be that if $a>0$ then $|a|=a$ and if $a,b>0$ then $a+b>0$, thus, $a+b=|a+b|$

Comment: Ok but is my proof any good ?

Comment: It seems correct. But a bit messy.

Comment: Messy ? I think I forgot to add superior and equal. Not just superior.

Comment: @copper Your using that $|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$ which is correct, but the argument is simpler if you use the equivalent definition given in the comment above.

Comment: @copper: Notice that your proof is the same approach, in that you are going the equivalent steps.  However, you are consistently needing to square and root to go back and forth between |x| and x, where you can go directly in the case x > 0.  It's common for mathematicians, when they see they are doing the same thing over and over, to factor out that work as a lemma.  Here, the lemma |x|=x (x>0) can be shown using the root and square method (or by the definition, depending on definition given) and then used over and over.

Comment: Sorry I'm kinda new to proofs. Btw, I just completed my case where -a and -b < = 0 although it's kinda long for nothing. Want to see it ?

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten your approach and deal with the negative case at the same time, by writing
$$
(|a|+|b|)^2=a^2+2|a||b| + b^2\stackrel{(1)}=a^2+2ab+b^2=(a+b)^2\tag{*}
$$
where (1) uses the fact that $|a||b|=ab$ if $a$ and $b$ have the same sign. Now take square roots of both ends of (*).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the characteritic that $|a| = \sqrt{a^2}$ you certainly can.

$(|a|+|b|)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2 |ab|$

if |ab| = ab then
$(|a|+|b|)^2 = (a+b)^2$

$||a|+|b|| = |a+b|$

$|a|+|b| = |a+b|$